# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scala": CreateProcess error=2,

Tags: java, windows, scala

I want  to compile this:

```
import scala.sys.process._

val output = "scala".!!
```

but shows me this:

**java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scala": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**

this does't work too:

```
val cmd = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\scala\\bin\\scalac.bat\\\""

val output = "cmd".!!
```

also my environment variables are fine. (for java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\ and scala: **C:\Program Files (x86)\scala** and path variable: **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** and **%SCALA_HOME%\bin**

Typing "scala" in cmd work.
And this code work too:

```
import scala.sys.process._

val output = "java".!!
```

Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

command `scala` is a REPL with interactive console. And you are trying to run interactive command from interactive console?

It should work with any non-interactive commands like `ls -l`(`DIR` in dindows) or `date` smoothly as following examples (in unix),

```
scala> val output = "date".!!
output: String =
"Mon May 15 14:52:54 PDT 2017
"
```

or

```
scala> val output = "java -version".!!
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
output: String = ""
```

or,

```
scala> Seq("echo", "urayagppd") #>> new File("mylogs.log")
res2: scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder =  ( [echo, urayagppd] #| /Users/prayagupd/myrepo/mylogs.log )
```

**But to run something interactive process like ssh or something else,**

```
scala> val scalaProcess = Process("""scala""")
scalaProcess: scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder = [scala]

scala> val exitCode = scalaProcess.!
Welcome to Scala 2.12.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :quit
exitCode: Int = 1

scala> val p = scalaProcess.run
p: scala.sys.process.Process = scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$SimpleProcess@af9dd34

scala> Welcome to Scala 2.12.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :quit

scala> val exitCode = p.exitValue
exitCode: Int = 1
```

Comment: it still does't work when i type val scalaProcess = Process("""scala -version""") but when i type val scalaProcess = Process("""java -version""") then work well.

Comment: when i type val scalaProcess = Process("""scala -version""") but when i type val scalaProcess = Process("""java -version""") then work well.

Comment: whats the error? `Process("""scala -version""").!` is working fine.

Comment: error is the same. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scala": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified. ;(

Comment: are you running from command prompt or from IDE? can you verify you can use scala from comman prompt `C:\>scala --version`

Comment: I'm running from command prompt and when i type in cmd `scala -version` works fine but when i `val scalaProcess = Process("""scala -version""")`  form REPL then error ;(

Comment: do you think it is `scala.exe -version` or `scala.bat -version` in windows or you think `scala -version` should work? I don't have a windows machine to verify it. _simply `scala -version` works in Unix/Linux._

Comment: Finally works. `scala.bat -version` and `scala.bat` and evrything with .bat :) Thank you so much @prayagupd.